# Iterate over a list and add items another list SCALA

Tags: list, scala

**I have a list like this:**

```
val list = List(("A", List("B", "C")),("B", List("A", "C", "D")))
```

**And I want to return a list like this**

```
newlist = List(("A","B",List("B","C")),("A","C",List("B","C")),("B","A",List("A", "C", "D")),("B","C",List("A", "C", "D")),("B","D",List("A", "C", "D")))
```

How can i do it with `map`? How can i do it with `for`?

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: And what are those curly braces doing there ? That is not Scala.

Comment: I mean: ({a, b}, bs) where b is an element of bs. 
The curly braces are to explain what I want. Thank you!

Comment: If the curly braces "are to explain" what you want, they aren't getting it done.

Comment: Please write out, in correct Scala, what you want `newlist` to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be what you're after.

```
val lst = List(("A", List("B", "C")),("B", List("A", "C", "D")))
lst.flatMap{case (s,l) => l.map((s,_,l))}
res0: List[(String, String, List[String])] = List((A,B,List(B, C)), (A,C,List(B, C)), (B,A,List(A, C, D)), (B,C,List(A, C, D)), (B,D,List(A, C, D)))
```

As a `for` comprehension it might look like this.

```
for {
  t <- lst              //for every tuple from lst
  s <- t._2             //for every string from tuple's 2nd element
} yield (t._1, s, t._2) //create new tuple (triple)
```